# Select rows having number of different values in columns

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have a table like

```
a | b | c
--+---+--
1 | 1 | 2
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 2 | 2
3 | 2 | 3
```

I want to select rows, which have a number of different values WITHIN this row. Something like:

```
select a,b,c from table having size(unique(a,b,c)) = 2
```

So for the given set of data, this case the query returns:

```
a | b | c
--+---+--
1 | 1 | 2
1 | 2 | 2
3 | 2 | 3
```

Is there a mysql-operand for this kind of thing? Obviously I need to use this with more rows and different values as 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a neat way of doing this, in case of a,b,c are id's of one table. Then you can do a subquery and do an in predicate like this:

```
select 
    a,b,c, 
    (select count(distinct(*)) from table where id in (a,b,c)) number
from table 
having number = x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a,b,c from table WHERE a != b AND b != c AND a != c
```

Comment: I need to use this with 2,3,4,5... ;)

Comment: `select DISTINCT(a) a ,DISTINCT(b) b,DISTINCT(c) c from table` Could this work?